# Remove specific files from a directory

Tags: shell, ubuntu

We have some files in a certain folder under this name format **BKK-20170428082153.war**

we need to remove all the files which are one week older from the current date.

i have tried this command `find . -name "*.war" -type f -delete`, but it doesn't check the date rule that i want.

can anyone help me out.

Comment: Please accept one of the answers below or describe why they do not match your needs.

Answer (score 1):

The answers given are excellent and should serve you.

I you still want deletion based on the filename and not based on the timestamps try this.

```
alias delete-weeks-war='for i in {1..7};do rm BKK-`date -v-${i}d +%Y%m%d`*.war; done'
```

## Usage

```
$ cd wars-directory
$ delete-weeks-war # simple as ... that
```

## Explanation

```
# traverses the last seven days starting from yesterday
# set to 0..6 to start from today
for i in {1..7} 
do
    # calculates timestamp, only the part of year, month, day
    t=`date -v-${i}d +%Y%m%d` 
    # builds the expected file name
    # to cover all combinations for hour, time and seconds there is the asterisk
    file="BKK-${t}*.war"
    # removes the designated files
    rm $file
    # if no files found you will get an error like
    # rm: BKK-20170428*.war: No such file or directory
    # to get rid of this error message use the following rm instead of the previous
    # rm $file 2>/dev/null
done
```

I believe it matches perfectly your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `-ctime`:

- find files more than 7 days ago: -ctime +7
- find files less than 7 days ago: -ctime -7
- find files xactly 7 days ago: -ctime 7

So you want to use `find . -ctime -7`

`ctime` checks "change of file status information". There is also `atime` which checks "last access time" and `mtime` which checks "last modification time". See the man page of find for more details.

Answer (score 0):

`a` + `time` == access or read the file, or`-atime`
`c` + `time` == change in a file attributes or modify, or `-ctime`
`m` + `time` == change the content of the file or modify, or `-mtime`

---

`+` means greater then a specific time, like: `+7`
`-` means less than a specific time, like `-7`
`number` means exactly that number, like `7`

---

for your purpose ( **based on modifying the content** ):

```
find . -name '*.war' -type f -mtime +7
```